# Unable to connect Powershell Azure AD module on Win10

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to connect Azure AD , I am running PowerShell in elevated type "connect-azuread"

Since I have different global Admin id then my login credentials on windows 10 I enter GA account.

I think this is related to user context but not sure how to fix ?

**Request Id:  0d6cd71d-b57b-4047-b957-bd7g1c5c3b00

Correlation Id:  adb18825-dhb5-42ef-ba42-a0d246e3618c 
Timestamp:  2020-05-12T13:23:27Z

Message:  AADSTS90100: ctx parameter is empty or not valid.**

Comment: Have you enabled MFA on GA account?  If multi-factor authentication is enabled for your credentials, you must log in using the interactive option or use service principal authentication.

Comment: it is enabled and I can log in If I go to PowerShell path and open PowerShell run as a different user and enter my GA account details however If I open PowerShell run as admin which uses current logged in user and try to connect Azure ad. After entering GA account creds it gives me error. FYI everything is interactive here nothing is silent

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Could you please check if the current logged in user has administrator rights?

Comment: Thanks, Nishant for your reply, Yes the current user has admin right on the machine. I think there is something wrong with win 10 that you can not use any other account due to IWA and it gives me the error but there is nothing much relevant is available.